# Custom ADO.Net Provider for NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net

My Company is working with a Database called U2 Universe.
The Database Manufacturer provided us with a ADO.Net provider which works with Microsoft's Entity Framework.

Is it possible to extend NHibernate to make it work with the ADO.Net provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is. You need to implement `IDriver` and `Dialect` (you can use `GenericDialect`, but it's usually too limited)

For examples, look at the source of existing [drivers](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Driver) and [dialects](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect).